# rails query has_many through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 4 classes: `User`, `Platform` and `Listing` and `Item`.

User has many platforms.

Platform has many items through listings.

Listing belongs to item and belongs to platform.

Item has many listings.

**How would I go about getting all the users items?**

My existing solution (which involves an in-efficient in-memory solution) is this:

```
user.platforms.includes(:items).inject([]) { |result, x| result + x.items }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add relation in your `User` model. ActiveRecord will take care about your query.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :platforms
  has_many :items, through: :platforms
end
```

Comment: I want to keep the user separate from the platforms. Any solutions without adding a has_many to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query started from `Item` and use `user.id` as parameter.

```
Item.joins(:platforms).where("platform.user_id = ?", user.id)
```

Comment: Item does not belong to platform... The relationship is that:Platform has many items through listings.

Listing belongs to item and belongs to platform.

Item has many listings.

Comment: So why don't you add this relation?